# ruby script to enter prompt command from a system command

Tags: ruby, scripting, mysql

I'm trying to write a simple script to mysqldump some dbs.  I'm getting stuck on the password prompt though.

I'd like to just have a config file that contains all the db creds, then the script can use those to connect to the db.

Problem is a command such as:

```
system('mysqldump -u username -p')
```

then prompts for

```
Enter password:
```

even when I do something like:

```
system('mysqldump -u username -p some_password')
```

I still get prompted for the password...

I don't do a whole lot of scripting in Ruby so I'm at a loss as to how my script can automatically enter this info so the user running the script doesn't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to delete space after `-p`

```
system('mysqldump -uusername -psome_password')
```

or without password just

```
system('mysqldump -uusername')
```

or

```
system('mysqldump -uusername --password=')
```

Comment: amazing, that worked!  Now, for bonus marks, what do I do if my db has an empty password?  omitting the -p doesn't work as it still apparently contains a password, just a blank one

Comment: just said that doesn't work... it *has* a password apparently, but it's empty. omitting -p gives me an `access denied using password YES`

Comment: oh :) I thought empty password means no password

Comment: apparently they're different??

Comment: why don't you just reset it or make a real password? How do you connect to your database out of ruby?

Comment: it works in ruby with just a blank password (rails database.yml config)

Comment: to be honest, i'm just going with it like this, user can just hit enter anyway, not too big a deal, thanks again!

Comment: So try this `system('mysqldump -uusername --password=')`

Comment: funny. I've just tryed. Works fine. Here is something wrong with your user password

Comment: My advice is to create new MySQL user without password and work with this user

Answer (score 2):

If you already know the password why aren't you passing it to the command?

```
system('mysqldump -u username --password=mypassword')
```

Comment: Sorry, there should be an `=` in there.

Comment: ah, ya that would have sufficed also...  fl00r beat you to it unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

you could always check the application that uses the database for the password, check the config file file for the connection string. Failing that change the password in the database.